# Where do I find the Facebook application id for the the fb_social module?

Tags: 7, social-network

I just installed the [fb_social module](http://drupal.org/project/fb_social). Now I need to set up the module which requires the Facebook application id.

Under the field reads: **Get the ID of your facebook app or create a new facebook app : here.**

But the link drive me to the main page of my facebook account.

Where is the right place to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Login as FB app admin
2. Go here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps
3. Copy the destination for "Edit settings" link for your app
4. Take app ID from the URL. This is the pattern: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[your app ID]/summary

Comment: If I try to go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps I'm redirected to my panel page http://www.facebook.com/pages/myBusinessName/. I guess I should logout and login as FB app admin. Where? Do I need to create an **FB App Admin account** ?

Comment: Login first and then go to developers subsite. Just login with the account you associated with the application (the one you used to create it).

Comment: I think I don't get it. I didn't create a app. I just enable the fb_social module and create a Preset to create show a Facebook livestream plugin to be shown as a block.

Comment: Do I need to create an app in the facebook website to pair with the Preset?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a FB application first.